# Golang parse YAML with predefined struct as well as dynamic values

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I'm having some trouble parsing a static/dynamic YAML file with Go.
This is the YAML file I'm using

```
  #this part is fixed
  stack:
    platformName: 'default'
    stack-image-name: 'stack-v1'
    stack-image-version: '1.5.2'
    structure: 'flat'

  #This part is dynamic and can change     

  # ===== Apache Zookeeper ========
  ZOOKEEPER_enable: false
  ZOOKEEPER_volume_map_data: false
  ZOOKEEPER_nodes: 1            # either 1 or 3
  ZOOKEEPER_navigator_enable: false
  
  # ===== Apache Kafka ========
  KAFKA_enable: false
  # one of enterprise, community
  KAFKA_edition: 'community'
  KAFKA_volume_map_data: false
  KAFKA_broker_nodes: 3
  KAFKA_delete_topic_enable: false
  KAFKA_auto_create_topics_enable: false

  #kafka schema registry
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_enable: false
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_nodes: 1
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_use_zookeeper_election: false
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_replication_factor: 1

  #kafka connect
  KAFKA_CONNECT_enable: false
  KAFKA_CONNECT_nodes: 2

  #ksqldb
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_enable: false
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_edition: 'oss'
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_nodes: 1

  #confluent control center
  KAFKA_CCC_enable: false

  KAFKA_RESTPROXY_enable: false
  KAFKA_MQTTPROXY_enable: false

  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_UI_enable: false
  KAFKA_TOPICS_UI_enable: false
  KAFKA_CONNECT_UI_enable: false

  KAFKA_CMAK_enable: false
  KAFKA_KAFDROP_enable: false
  KAFKA_KADMIN_enable: false
  KAFKA_AKHQ_enable: false
  KAFKA_BURROW_enable: false

  # ===== Hadoop ========
  HADOOP_enable: false
  HADOOP_datanodes: 2

  # ===== Spark ========
  SPARK_enable: false
  # "hive" or "in-memory"
  SPARK_catalog: in-memory
  SPARK_workers: 2
  SPARK_jars_packages: ''
  SPARK_jars_ivySettings: ''
  SPARK_driver_extraJavaOptions: ''
  SPARK_executor_extraJavaOptions: ''
```

below are the structs

```
type YAMLFile struct {
    Stack Stack `yaml:"stack"`
    Services              map[string]interface{}
}
type Stack struct {
    PlatformName      string `yaml:"platformName"`
    StackImageName    string `yaml:"stack_image_name"`
    StackImageVersion string `yaml:"stack-image-version"`
    Structure         string `yaml:"structure"`

}
```

This is how I'm parsing the file

```
var yamlFile YAMLFile

        if configFile == "" {
            log.Fatal("Unable to run command as configFile is null")
            return
        }
        ymlContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFile)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(ymlContent, &yamlFile)
```

The content under the stack is properly parsed into the stack struct however I cannot find the way to have the rest to be parsed into a dynamic map or collection; I've tried `map[interface{}]interface{}` as well as a struct or `map[string]interface{}` but the Stack property is always `nil`

Any ideas? I found a lot of posts about parsing YAML but none worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the struct you have defined to have the rest of the yaml fields to be parsed into a map in the way you want

This is because your struct is of the form,

```
type YAMLFile struct {
    Stack    Stack                  `yaml:"stack"`
    Services map[string]interface{}
}
```

When you try to unmarshal your file using this struct it will look for a field named "services" in your yaml file(because that's the name of the struct field). And since there is no such field the struct map value is empty.

There are 2 ways to parse a dynamic yaml file whose structure is unknown.
If you want the rest of the yaml file, apart from the stack field values, to be parsed into your map then you have to change your yaml file to match your struct. Like this,

```
#this part is fixed
stack:
  platformName: "default"
  stack-image-name: "stack-v1"
  stack-image-version: "1.5.2"
  structure: "flat"

#This part is dynamic and can change

# ===== Apache Zookeeper ========
services:
  ZOOKEEPER_enable: false
  ZOOKEEPER_volume_map_data: false
  ZOOKEEPER_nodes: 1 # either 1 or 3
  ZOOKEEPER_navigator_enable: false

  # ===== Apache Kafka ========
  KAFKA_enable: false
  # one of enterprise, community
  KAFKA_edition: "community"
  KAFKA_volume_map_data: false
  KAFKA_broker_nodes: 3
  KAFKA_delete_topic_enable: false
  KAFKA_auto_create_topics_enable: false

  #kafka schema registry
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_enable: false
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_nodes: 1
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_use_zookeeper_election: false
  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_replication_factor: 1

  #kafka connect
  KAFKA_CONNECT_enable: false
  KAFKA_CONNECT_nodes: 2

  #ksqldb
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_enable: false
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_edition: "oss"
  KAFKA_KSQLDB_nodes: 1

  #confluent control center
  KAFKA_CCC_enable: false

  KAFKA_RESTPROXY_enable: false
  KAFKA_MQTTPROXY_enable: false

  KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_UI_enable: false
  KAFKA_TOPICS_UI_enable: false
  KAFKA_CONNECT_UI_enable: false

  KAFKA_CMAK_enable: false
  KAFKA_KAFDROP_enable: false
  KAFKA_KADMIN_enable: false
  KAFKA_AKHQ_enable: false
  KAFKA_BURROW_enable: false

  # ===== Hadoop ========
  HADOOP_enable: false
  HADOOP_datanodes: 2

  # ===== Spark ========
  SPARK_enable: false
  # "hive" or "in-memory"
  SPARK_catalog: in-memory
  SPARK_workers: 2
  SPARK_jars_packages: ""
  SPARK_jars_ivySettings: ""
  SPARK_driver_extraJavaOptions: ""
  SPARK_executor_extraJavaOptions: ""
```

As you can see I have moved the rest of the file's content under a field called "services", this is so that it can be unmarshalled as you expect into your struct.

OR

The other way is don't use your struct and treat the whole file as dynamic instead of treating part of the file as dynamic.
If you follow this method then you can change your code to this,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {

    yamlMap := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    ymlContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(ymlContent, &yamlMap)
    fmt.Printf("%v", yamlMap)
}
```

Comment: this is what I was afraid of, at first I was doing it this way but the fixed part is mandatory, however I cannot change the structure of the YAML file so I'll revert to full dynamic. thanks